# Sending column from sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

There are two tables one transaction and other customer. I am getting multiple rows of `customerid` and service time, but I want customer name (which is in customer table) and service time. So I tried below query which is not working.

```
select name,service_time from CUSTOMER,TRANSACTION
WHERE id IN 
(
    select customer_id,service_time from TRANSACTION 
    where  service_date='$date' and employee_id='$employee_id'
);
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you clarify your first sentence.

Comment: Why are you selecting 2 columns in the sub-query?

Comment: @bill i want to use service_time which i fetched from subquery along with name.@ullas because i want both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN`

```
SELECT c.name, t.service_time 
  FROM CUSTOMER AS c
  JOIN TRANSACTION AS t ON t.customer_id = c.id
 WHERE t.service_date = '$date' 
   AND employee_id = '$employee_id'
```

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL Join Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)
- [Data Visualization with JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294854/767881)